# OpenCV SurfFeatureDetector principles of working

Tags: opencv

By what principle SurfFeatureDetector finds the keypoints?. In other words, what qualities should has the part of the image to be caught as a keypoint?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stackoverflow responses should be more than a link, but your question cannot be answered in less than a good, full-size scientific paper. Go directly to source:

[Here](http://www.chrisevansdev.com/computer-vision-opensurf.html) you find a detailed description of the algorithm. Look for the "Notes on the OpenSURF Library" pdf.